# Storage class that with one instance

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to create such class `Storage` for storing data, like a cache, so every class would have access to either update values in `Storage` or get the latest updated values.

But then I would like to have another functionality that removes all the values from `Storage` (like creates a new instance) to start overwriting them again from multiple classes.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have you tried and failed? You just make a field on a class that is of type Storage, and pass in a Storage in it's constructor.

Comment: keywords for your reseaches: `singleton`, `static`

Comment: @RyanTheLeach But constructor will create a new instance, and if I have multiple fields in `Storage` and want to update one of them by calling a constructor, I will lose the values of other fields.

Answer (score 2):

It might be not the exact thing you might want but this will work.

```
public class Storage
{
    private String data;   

    public Storage()
    {
        data = null;
    }

    public Storage(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Now is a limitations of the above Storage class.You can only store data of type String , you can very easily overcome this with the help of java generics just search about it.

> Now lets assume that you want to store some data for this you have to
>   do something like this.

```
Storage data1=new Storage("YOUR DATA HERE");
```

> `want to change the data then you can simply write`

```
data1.setData("UPDATED DATA");
```

> want to get the DAta write

```
data1.getData();
```

> want to reset the data write

```
data1.setData("");
```

And if you have multiple values in the Storage class then create different getters and setter for each of them .

Comment: @Logan thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem! I just encourage others to specify access modifiers. Otherwise they might run into the default package-private behavior.

Comment: How can I update the value of data from different classes? So from every class I would have the access to the latest updated value of data.

Comment: @user25963 I understood your problem just change private String data to private static String data. See more about static keyword

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible.

You simply `delegate` the getters and setters of a class, to the internal storage, and share that storage among several classes. This gets complicated if the other classes have state that needs to update on their own getters / setters.

Resetting can either be calling methods on the Storage directly, or you can introduce yet another layer of abstraction, and make Storage be a StorageHolder instead. with the `StorageHolder` acting as a `singleton` `container` for the Storage.

```
public class Q50694639 {
    public static class Storage {
        private int x;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }

    public static class SomeInstance {
        private Storage storage;

        public SomeInstance(Storage storage) {
            this.storage = storage;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return storage.getX();
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            storage.setX(x);
        }
    }

    public static class SomeInstance2 {
        private Storage storage;

        public SomeInstance2(Storage storage) {
            this.storage = storage;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return storage.getX();
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            storage.setX(x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Storage storage = new Storage();
        SomeInstance a = new SomeInstance(storage);
        SomeInstance b = new SomeInstance(storage);
        SomeInstance2 c = new SomeInstance2(storage);

        a.setX(1);
        System.out.println(a.getX());
        System.out.println(b.getX());
        System.out.println(c.getX());

        b.setX(2);
        System.out.println(a.getX());
        System.out.println(b.getX());
        System.out.println(c.getX());

        c.setX(3);
        System.out.println(a.getX());
        System.out.println(b.getX());
        System.out.println(c.getX());

        storage.setX(3);
        System.out.println(a.getX());
        System.out.println(b.getX());
        System.out.println(c.getX());
    }
}
```